# How many clients can be connected to my laptop hotspot?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I want to create a sever in my laptop (just an Apache web server running on Ubuntu that would sent Ajax reqests to PHP) and many people can reach it from a local network (my laptop hotspot).

Suppose I want to implement it in a classroom with 25+ students, is it feasible?

I want to know how many clients can be connected to the W-Fi hotspot? Are there any limitations?

Comment: This is largely hardware dependent.  A laptop is going to make a horrible server though.

Comment: localhost on ubuntu "Apache" -- question was updated

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a sever in my laptop (just an Apache web server
>   running on Ubuntu) and many people can reach it from a local network
>   (my laptop hotspot).
>
> Suppose I want to implement it in a classroom with 25+ students, is it
>   feasible?

For 25+ people using it a simple Apache-based web server running on a laptop should not be a problem. You could probably run a full WordPress, Drupal or other off-the-shelf CMS setup that way and it would not be an issue.

The only caveat to all of this is what else the laptop would be doing and how heavy-duty your Apache application might be. So just keep that in mind.

But in general, you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with a laptop hotspot is not the laptop, it is the bandwidth demand of 25 students all trying to access a file at the same time. If the laptop uses the common G series WLAN, the bandwidth is only 54 Megabits per second. This works out to less than 5.4 Megabytes per second because of the collision problem. A WLAN works like an old fashioned Hub Ethernet system, not a modern switched LAN.
My advice, if you use a lot of graphics, and unless you have the latest laptop, attach as fast an access point as you can afford to the laptop.

Comment: can repeater handle this problem ?